# Sleep within a script not affecting the terminal

Tags: bash, shell

I need a command within a shell script to wait for a while, is there a way how to use sleep so that it would run only within the script and I wouldn't have to wait until it is done?

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you show us some code?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the entire script in the background with `&`:

```
$ ./<scriptname> &
```

Which sounds like what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Run it in background using the `&`:

```
sleep 10 &
```

If want it to do something useful you can launch multiple commands in a sub shell:

```
(echo start; sleep 10 ; echo end) &
```

Or even write a shell script:

*script.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start"
sleep 10
echo "end"
```

and launch that in the background:

```
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh &
```

Further reading:

- [job control commands](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html), Advanced bash scripting guide
- [job control](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html#Job-Control), Bash manual

Comment: I have problems with the following code: cat /dev/urandom > testFile;
sleep 10 && pkill -f 'cat /dev/urandom'

Comment: That can't be what he needs. That command does nothing useful.

Comment: @ccarton Isn't sleeping something useful? I would welcome the opportunity at the moment! :) ... No, it was just an example how to launch a command in background.

Comment: Sleeping is useful. Running a command in the background is useful. Running a sleep command in the background is not useful.

Comment: Ok, if you say so. I mean you see that this is for educational reasons, aren't you?

Comment: @ccarton If you have a signal handler and your script receives a signal, it cannot run the handler until after `sleep` finishes. Running `sleep` in the background and immediately `wait`ing on it fixes the problem, since `wait` is interruptible.